# Python exclude CWD file in proc

Tags: python

I have a script called `client` that does a few things around the OS and it's failing when it comes to `/proc/1/cwd`

I'm trying to ignore these types of files but the script is still crashing when it comes to this file. I get `Memory Map` output and also a `Stack Trace` before the script crashes.

I did a `file /proc/1/cwd` command on the file and I can see it's a symlink, where I then included an `if os.path.islink(file) is False:` IF statement to skip it and proceed.

However, I seem to still be hitting it.

The below is the Traceback after the crash.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 235, in <module>
  File "client.py", line 120, in runner
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/proc/1/cwd'
Failed to execute script client
```

**The error suggests the script `client` is working on `/proc/1/cwd` and then right after seems to say that it can't execute itself?**

Any help would be appreciated.

**-----Additional -------**

Code lines from error:

**like 235** is literally the line `runner(path)`

`runner()` represents a function that has a for loop that cycles through files in a folder to find the correct file. During this process, runner will do the following:

1. do line 120 `mode = os.stat(fullfilename).st_mode`
2. check `if os.path.isdir(fullfilename) is False:`
3. then `if stat.S_ISREG(mode) is True:`
4. then `if os.path.islink(fullfilename) is False:`
5. then `if fullfilename not in blacklist:`

**Line 120**  is `mode = os.stat(fullfilename).st_mode`

Comment: What is the value of file here `os.path.islink(file)`? and the Permission level of this file `/proc/1/cwd`

Comment: The file is owned by `root:root` (I don't want to open it or use it)... the value of `os.path.islink(file) == True`

Comment: would the best way to identify it be `os.path.islink()`  ?

Comment: Please share line number 120 and 235 of the client.py file.

Comment: I have included the lines mentioned in the code.

Comment: In the /proc filesystem with the process Id 1,  there are three link files, viz. `(/proc/1/cwd, /proc/1/exe, /proc/1/root)`. It is not possible to get the mode of these files via `os.stat()`

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Would you suggest I hard code an exclusion for these 3 files or how will I be able to detect files like them?

Comment: `ls -l` on the /proc/1 will give an indication that these are the link files.